# Loop Multiple URLs Through the Same API Information

Tags: python, json, api, loops

I am looking to loop a list of URLs through the same API key and base URL to extract the data from their JSON outputs. I can't seem to set up the loop properly.

Here's where I at:

```
page_URL = ['https://www.usatoday.com','https://www.capitalone.com']

for url in page_URL:
   API_Key = "xyz"
   baseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url="
   strategy = "mobile"
   response_url = baseURL+page_URL+'&key='+API_Key+'&strategy='+strategy
   response = requests.get(response_url).json()
   url_id = response['originLoadingExperience']['id']
   overall_score = response['lighthouseResult']['categories']['performance']['score']*100
   fcp_score = response['originLoadingExperience']['metrics']['FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS']['percentile']/1000
   fid_score = response['originLoadingExperience']['metrics']['FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_MS']['percentile']
   lcp_score = response['originLoadingExperience']['metrics']['LARGEST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS']['percentile']/1000
   cls_score = response['originLoadingExperience']['metrics']['CUMULATIVE_LAYOUT_SHIFT_SCORE']['percentile']/100
```

The obvious issue is trying to concatenate my `page_URL` list with `response_URL`, which is not a list, but I don't know how to correct this.

Grateful for any solutions.

Comment: `baseURL+page_URL+'&key='+API_Key+'&strategy='+strategy` should be `baseURL+url+'&key='+API_Key+'&strategy='+strategy`. You want to use the `url` defined in your loop

Comment: Do NOT share the API key

Comment: @C_Z_ you're a master.

Comment: @balderman really appreciate the heads up

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. The first one was addressed by the comment made by @C_Z_5. The second issue is that when you send a query string for a GET request, the parameter names and values must be encoded so as to not contain certain characters (e.g. '?', '=', '&', ':', '/', etc.). The URL's in the `page_URL` list have such special characters and so you can use the `quote_plus` function to encode such values:

```py
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
...
for url in page_URL:
   ...
   response_url = baseURL+quote_plus(url)+'&key='+API_Key+'&strategy='+strategy
   ... # etc.
```

Note that it general it cannot hurt to apply the `quote_plus` function to each of the keyword/value pairs (i.e. every keyword and value following the '?' in the URL) if you are not sure if their contents are "safe."

It would have been really problematic if any of the URLs in `page_URL` contained a query string. Since none did, you might get away without encoding the URLs using `quote_plus`. But better safe than sorry.